Register page gives error at authentication process
I am doing the signUp page in flutter for two types of users (business / client) but I don't know how to incorporate this detail for the firebase authentication. I also have some problems in the signUp() method down the code... when user≠ null I receive an error and also context has a red line. I want customer user to be send to Homepage and business user to GetStartedScreen().
Here is a screenshot of the error that occurred in the SignUp() method:

And here is the code
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

var elements1 = [
  'Customer',
  'Business',
];
String dropdownvalue = 'Customer';
TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
bool isSigningUp = false;
final FirebaseAuthServices _auth = FirebaseAuthServices();

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _usernameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Logo(),
              SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              LoginButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}

class SignUpButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _usernameController,
                hintText: "Username",
                isPasswordField: false,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _emailController,
                hintText: "Email",
                isPasswordField: false,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _passwordController,
                hintText: "Password",
                isPasswordField: true,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
              height: 62,
              width: 350,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              child: DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                value: dropdownvalue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items: elements1.map((String items) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items));
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? value) {},
              )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 62,
            width: 350,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                  )),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocationPage()));
              },
              child: Text(
                'Sign Up',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.email,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
          ])
        ])),
      ],
    );
  }

  void signUp() async {
    String username = _usernameController.text;
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;

    User? user = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    if (user≠ null){
      print("User is successfully created");
      Navigator.pushNamed ( context, "/Users/lilianasanda/influfit/lib/getstarted_screed1.dart");
    } else {
      print("Some error happend");
    }
  }
}


For the firebase part, you are right it only take email and password. I see two ways for that problem.

First : You build your own database around firebase authentification
Second : You save the user type with a package like SharedPreferences which will work when the user doesn't change phone or delete the app.

Of course the first way is the rational one to choose for a long term project, but if you just need a little tool second one might be less time consuming.
And for your function, you might want to change if (user≠ null){ by if (user != null). The second error is that your function is missing the Build context of your build function, you might want to give the context through your parameters.
Hope it helps you, have a good day

I should edit like : void _signUp(Buildcontex context) async {...} ? because when I do this and change onPressed function with signUp it get red

Does your onPressed looks like something like this :
onPressed: () {                signUp(context);             }
?
